# Get results for specific facebook marketing campaigns objectives

Tags: facebook, facebook-ads-api, facebook-marketing-api

Each Facebook ad campaign has an [objective](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-campaign-group), such as `LINK_CLICKS` or `CONVERSIONS`.

In Ad Manager, one can see the performance of each of their ad campaigns.  There is a column called "results" that has the number of objective-specific conversions for that campaign.  So for example, if the objective is `PAGE_LIKES` then [results would show the number of page likes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lmcutm.png) resulting from the campaign, but if the objective was `LINK_CLICKS` then results would show website clicks.

My question is: Is there something in the Insights API that equates to the results column in Ad Manager?  Part of the reason I ask is for ease and consistency, but also some of the objectives are ambiguous, e.g. `BRAND_AWARENESS`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I haven't been able to easily replicate the `results` and `cost per result` columns from the ad manager with an API call.

First you can check the `URL` when in the ad manager to see which columns are selected by looking at the GET parameter `columns`:

```
https://business.facebook.com/ads/manage/powereditor/manage/ads?act=...&business_id=..&columns=name%2Cerrors%2Cdelivery%2Cresults%2Creach%2Cimpressions%2Ccost_per_result&...
```

Decoding this gives the following fields:

```
columns=name,errors,delivery,results,reach,impressions,cost_per_result
```

Now it looks like we could simply use the `result` and `cost_per_result` fields, but that gives an error:

> (#100) results, cost_per_result are not valid for fields param.

This is expected as the [API document](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/insights/fields/) doesn't specify `results` and `cost_per_result` as valid fields.

Now when in the ad manager we can also see the API calls use the `network` tab of `developer tools` to see it making API calls to retrieve data. This shows us the `result` and `cost_per_result` fields being used. You can actually copy the request URl and see it working... somehow..

Trying to recreate this API call in the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) only worked for me when I copied the access token from the previous call. This makes me feel that the business manager has a special access token.